# how to match any string in Emacs regexp?

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm referring to this page: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_regex.html

which says that to capture a pattern in Emacs Regexp, you need to escape the paren like this: `\(myPattern\)`.

It further says that the syntax for capturing a sequence of ASCII characters is `[[:ascii:]]+`

In my document, I'm trying to match all strings that occur between `<p class="calibre3">` and `</p>`

So, following the syntax above, I do a replace-regexp for

`<p class="calibre3">\([[:ascii:]]+\)</p>`

but it finds no matches.

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have some non-ascii (codes 0-127) characters. Perhaps some unicode?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`<p class="calibre3">\([^<]\)+</p>`

Source: @TooTone

Comment: (I based my solution on Dave's substitution of [^<] for [[::ascii::]])

Answer (score 3):

Regexps are not good for general-purpose HTML parsing, but as paragraph tags cannot be validly nested, the following is going to be fine (provided the mark-up is valid & well-formed).

```
<p class="calibre3">\(.*?\)</p>
```

`*?` is the non-greedy zero-or-more repetitions operator, so it will match as little as possible -- in this case everything until the next `</p>` (as opposed to the greedy version, which would match everything until the final `</p>` in the text).

The `[^<]` approach is fine if it fits the data in question, but it won't work if there are other tags within the paragraphs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are regexps not good for HTML parsing? What's a superior alternative?

Comment: There's no end of searchable discussion on the former. An in-built superior alternative for general-purpose HTML parsing is http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parsing-HTML_002fXML.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape your angle brackets and I would use [^<] instead of [[:ascii]] like so:

```
\<p class="calibre3"\>([^<]+\)</p\>
```

Comment: You're missing a \ in the closing `</p>`... I fixed it and tried it, but still no matches. Even though my document contains lots of strings like this `<p class="calibre3">1 April Fool 3</p>`

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to escape angle brackets, this worked for me `<p class="calibre3">\([^<]\)+</p>`

Comment: @TooTone your syntax `<p class="calibre3">\([^<]\)+</p>` worked!

Comment: It is unnecessary, `\>` and `\<` are beginning/end of word matches in emacss regexp flavour.